# Configuration of Content Security Policy to retrieve images from remote URL and local

Tags: html, angular, content-security-policy

I have configured the Content-Security-Policy meta like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src *;
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

However, I'm still getting `Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:`

How can this be possible? What I'd like to achieve is to enable data from a remote URL like: https://example.com and 'self'. For this, I had tried different options like, but none of them worked.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src https://example.com 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src https: 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

I'm using images like in Angular where the 'image' value contains the remote image URL.

```
<img [defaultImage]="'assets/images/product/placeholder.jpg'"
    [lazyLoad]="image"
    [alt]="image" class="img-fluid" [src]="image">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little typo here `https//example.com` should be `https://example.com` or with a wildcard `*.example.com`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src *.example.com 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Comment: Thanks it turned out that it was a server side configuration enforcing the policy. But thanks anyway!